# Why isn't my Antdesign Icon appearing on screen?

Tags: react-native, icons, font-awesome, ant-design-pro, react-native-vector-icons

**Hello, I am having trouble with my AntDesign Icon appearing on the screen the only thing that does pop up is just an X I am using react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign. If somebody can please show me how I can have my Icons show up on my screen it would be greatly appreciated!**

```
import React, { useContext, useRef, useState } from "react"; // we are importing the react library and the useContext hook from react and we are importing the Context from the global context file
import { Context } from "../globalContext/globalContext.js"
import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import FontAwesome5 from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
import Sound from 'react-native-sound';
import Video from 'react-native-video';
import { Button, Input, Image, Tile } from 'react-native-elements';
import LottieView from 'lottie-react-native';
import {
    SafeAreaView,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    //Image,
    ImageBackground,
    Animated,
    StatusBar,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Pressable,
    Alert,

} from 'react-native';


 return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
                <LottieView style={styles.lottie} source={require('C:/Users/Raffp/Desktop/React Native Projects/React_Native_FoodApp3/CheeseBurgerApp/assets/imgs/59677-fast-food.json')} autoPlay loop  />
                <View style={styles.header}>
                 <Text style={styles.text_header}>Pristine Burgers</Text><FontAwesome5 name="hotdog" size={50} color="gold" />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.footer}>
                    <Animated.View style={[styles.textWrapper, animatedStyles]}>
                        <Text style={styles.text_footer}>Take More Then Just Bite</Text>
                    </Animated.View>
                    <Pressable
                        style={styles.button}
                        onPress={() => {
                            textAnimation();
                            setTimeout(() => {
                            navigation.navigate('');
                            }, 1000);
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text style={styles.text_footer}>Yum!</Text>
                        <AntDesign name="arrowright" size={24} color="white" />
                    </Pressable>
                </View>
            </View>
    );
}
```

[X Appearing on the screen instead of
the icon?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aclSV.png)

Answer (score 0):

I find that I run into issues like this when I miss a step when installing the package. You could try redoing the additional installation steps for your platform. See the documentation for [iOS installation](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#ios) and [Android installation](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#android).